# Ssh2 sftp returns 502 Bad gateway using PHP

Tags: php, apache, sftp, ssh2-sftp

Im trying to upload an image to a sftp server with the following code:

```
//$this->sftp is a fully functioning ssh2_sftp variable
$remotefile = "filename.jpg";
$url = "ssh2.sftp://". intval($this->sftp)."/".$remoteFile;
```

The image gets uploaded but the server returns a 502 HTTP Error.

I tried without the slash  `$url = "ssh2.sftp://". intval($this->sftp)."/".$remoteFile;` but I get the following error

> Failed to open stream: operation failed

Comment: What is generating the error? I don't think you're getting an HTTP error from an SSH connection.

Comment: Well, that's the question. The connection is not SSH but SFTP, and I don't really understand why adding a backslash makes the server return a 502 :C @AlexHowansky

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue, as this process is async I was closing the sftp connection before the process finished, triggering the 502 error.